# How do I update page height after jquery show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which is supposed to stay at the top of the viewport even when scrolling (position: absolute).

I have a some hidden elements that I display on demand with jquery function show().
If I show() a long element, I have a scrollbar appearing. If I scroll the top div doesn't follow the scrolling. It seems the new page height is ignored.

What to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing position:absolute with position:fixed (which is not supported by ie6 - workaround:http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/).

Also, make sure you have position: relative on your parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Just tossing this out there, [if you don't need to support IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t28), just use [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) with a `top:0` instead...no JavaScript required.